# How to combine IF conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, phpexcel

How to combine all four conditions and make one IF function

If C7<0,F7<0 should give G7

If C7>0,F7>0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if (C7+F7)>0,C7<0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if(C7+F7)<0,C7<0 should give G7-F7

if(C7+F7)>0,F7<0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if(C7+F7)<0,F7<0 should give G7

IF function combining all conditions

Comment: I realised my conditions were wrong

Comment: Can you please help me with this?